# Displaying both modes in a bimodal distribution

Tags: python, dictionary, statistics, mode

I'm having some trouble with my program that it is supposed to find the mode of a list of numbers.  It for the most part is working, however it is only displaying one mode when I know there is 2, and was wondering if there was anyway to display both of them.

```
    number_counts = {}
    mode = 0
    for i in order:
        if i in number_counts:
            number_counts[i] += 1
        else:
            number_counts[i] = 1
    for i in number_counts:
        most_values = max(number_counts.values())
    for key, value in number_counts.items():
        if  most_values == value:
            mode = key
```

Comment: is `mode = key` one of the modes you expect to see?

Comment: not sure what you mean ... mode is an integer. so why do you expect multiple values?

Comment: Also, the second for loop is useless, since you repeat the same operation independently of the iterator

Comment: yes, I print that mode later on in my code so I wanted to define my variable there.  and in certain cases there will be 2 numbers that happen the same amount of times and most often throughout the list

Comment: so mode needs to be a list

Comment: This is a simple two-liner using [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects). I also added a testcase which helps people understand why bimodal data causes an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can make a list of **modes** (plural):

```
modes = []
for key, value in number_counts.items():
        if  most_values == value:
            modes.append(key)
```

then deal with the list as you wish, for example:

```
number_of_modes = len(modes)
if number_of_modes == 1:
    print('There is only one mode: {}'.format(modes[0]))
else:
    print('There are {} modes:'.format(number_of_modes))
    for mode in modes:
        print(mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
number_counts = {}
mode = []
most_values = 0

for i in order:
    if i in number_counts:
        number_counts[i] += 1
    else:
        number_counts[i] = 1
    if number_counts[i] > most_values:
        most_values = number_counts[i]
for key, value in number_counts.iteritems():
    if  most_values == value:
        mode.append(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it using `collections.Counter` and its `most_common` method:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile
counter = Counter([1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7])
if counter: # Avoid IndexError on mostCommon below
    mostCommon = counter.most_common() # store once, avoid calling again
    maxCount = mostCommon[0][1] # maxCount is 2 for this example
    modes = [t[0] for t in takewhile(lambda x: x[1] == maxCount, mostCommon)]
else:
    modes = [] #  There are no modes for an empty iterable.
# Now modes references the list [1, 3]
```

Comment: why not use the `most_common` method  to get the max?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That was my first intuition, but the solution using `most_common` is actually uglier and less Pythonic IMO.

Comment: `mx = c.most_common(1)[0][0]` would be more efficient on a large data set.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well, it would be `c.most_common(1)[0][1]` since the 2nd item is the count. I've changed my answer to incorporate this even though I think it's less Pythonic.

Comment: Yes, a typo. I don't really see what is unpythonic about it, the method returns the most common element which is exactly what you want and avoids traversing every element in the dict again.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well, if we are focusing only on efficiency, I would write the code differently to avoid re-iteration and such, please see my edit above.

Comment: I was going to suggest `itertools.takewhile`  to do something similar

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Interesting, I've never read about that, I'll read about it and update the answer. I'm guessing that using `takewhile` is fast because the method call is a wrapper for a C module?

Comment: yes, it takes an iterable and a predicate and takes items until the predicate is False

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've changed my answer to use `itertools.takewhile`, thank you very much for showing it to me. I should study `itertools` more.

Comment: No worries, yes itertools have some really useful tools, definitely worth getting familiar with especially the recipes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple two-liner using [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
from collections import Counter

order = [3, 5, 4, 7, 4, 3, 4, 7, 3, 6]
number_counts = Counter(order)
>>>> Counter({3: 3, 4: 3, 7: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1})

modes = [val for val,count in number_counter.items()
             if count == max(number_counter.values()) ]
>>> [3, 4]
```

I wrote this independently of Shashank's and only read it later. `itertools.takewhile` is indeed an elegant way to get all the modes from `Counter.most_common()`